# How do I add my own items to the context menu of minimized applications in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In a Visual Studio c# Winforms application how do I go about adding my own items to the taskbar icon for my application?   For example the 'Sticky Notes' application has a 'New Note' option.   Is it possible for me to add my own items to my own application's taskbar icon?

[image: Example of a custom item in an application's taskbar context menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework
[msdn link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded it.  It seems to complicated for what I wanted to do - a task to 'send to notification area' that is only available while the app is minimized.   You have to be able to find the running instance and 'send' the task to the application as if from another app.  It doesn't seem possible to simply call a function directly within the app.